# Access to a value in a dataframe using another value

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's consider a simple dataframe :

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1=c("name1","name2","name3","name4"), x2=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4))
```

I would like to be able to use numeric values in x2 by calling their names defined in x1 (for example in a function). In fact, I would like name1,name2, name3,name4 to be the names of 4 different variables, and 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4 their values.

Do I have to use a pivotTable to transform my dataframe like this :

```
df1 <- data.frame("name1"=0.1, "name2"=0.2, "name3"=0.3,"name4"=0.4)
```

... or does it exist another solution ?

Comment: You mean this `setNames(df1$x2, df1$x1)`?

Comment: Is it not this a simple subset? `df1[ df1$x1 == "name1", "x2" ] `

Comment: Yes, I think this can solve my problem. But what is the object returned ? And how can I "call" the values of name1, name2... if I want to do some operations with it like name5 <- name1+name2 ?

Comment: `sum(df1[ df1$x1 %in% c("name1", "name2"), "x2" ])` ? I think your post/problem is oversimplified, try to give more context. Or as @Sotos suggested, convert it to a named vector, then address by name: `myX <- setNames(df1$x2, df1$x1); myX[ "name1" ] + myX[ "name2"]`

Comment: In addition to @Sotos, you can use `as.data.frame.list(setNames(df1$x2, df1$x1))` when you want a dataframe.

Comment: I think setNames() is the easiest solution ! And then I extract numeric values with [[ ]]